# XML Schema Validation: Use of maxOccurs and minOccurs dependant on other tag

Tags: xml, validation, schema

Ok here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileResults>
    <FileName>Results.xml</FileName>
    <DateTimeProcessed/>
    <TotalCount>10</TotalCount>
    <SuccessCount>8</SuccessCount>
    <FailureCount>2</FailureCount>
    <FailureRecords>
        <Record>
            <Data>
                <!--Some Data-->
            </Data>
            <Error>
                <ErrorCode>00089</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDescription>Datatype is invalid for field: Authorization_Code</ErrorDescription>
            </Error>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <Data>
                <!--Some Data-->
            </Data>
            <Error>
                <ErrorCode>00045</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDescription>Data is missing for field: Customer_Comments</ErrorDescription>
            </Error>
        </Record>
    </FailureRecords>
</FileResults>
```

Now my requirement is regarding validation of this XML. I have a schema for this XML which doing very well for the basic validation rules. I also want to validate the count of FailureRecords->Record tag. If the FailureCount's tag value is 2 then there should only be two Record tag occurences under FailureRecords tag. How to I enforce this.

I know there are minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes which control the number of appearences of a tag in XML but how to I assign the maxOccurs/minOccurs attribute values from another tag (which in my case is FailureCount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on a differnt logic layer. The XDS file just defines the structure independed from the content. It is impossible to check how many nodes are there depending on the content of one node.

You may could check that in a XSL(T) file which could count the rows and add a correct number or rows.